# Delayed differential equation is positive for all $t>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

if any one can  help me how to prove this theorem.

> Prove that for the IVP
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> x′(t)&=cx(t)[1−x(t−r)]\\
> x(\mu)&=\phi(\mu),\quad \mu \in [−r,0] 
> \end{aligned}
> \right\|
> $$
>   has for all $\phi \in C([−r,0],\mathbb{R})$  with  $\phi(0)>0$ a unique solution which exists and remains positive for all $t>0$.

Comment: Hint: $x(t-r)$ is a known function on $(0,r)$ so solve the equation there. Then you can continue to solve on $(r,2r)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can start treating this as a problem
$$
x'(t)=x(t)g(t),~~ x(0)=\phi(0),
$$
where you know the solution formula by separation,
$$
x(t)=\phi(0)\exp\left(\int_0^t g(s)\,ds\right).
$$
Now insert $g(s)=c[1-x(t-r)]$ to get
$$
x(t)=\phi(0)\exp\left(\int_{-r}^{t-r}c[1-x(s)] \,ds\right).
$$
This should tell you anything you need.

Comment: lutzl can you help me in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130471/how-to-find-stability-of-n-0-and-characteristic-equations-corresponding-to-posit